# IIS Log out issue for Asp.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, registry, global-asax

I have deployed Asp.Net website (not web application template) project in IIS. Anti-virus scans the application. so, customers facing log out issue. I already faced similar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172800/turn-off-files-folder-changes-in-global-asax-in-asp-net)

I can see the below error in Event Viewer whenever I face the log out issue

```
Event message: Application is shutting down. Reason: A subdirectory in the Bin application directory was changed or renamed.
```

With the help of @Zaitsman, I have come up with below code (code for global.asax) to resolve the issue

```
<%@ import namespace="System.Reflection"%>
private static bool hasRemovedFoldersFromMonitoring = false;
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!hasRemovedFoldersFromMonitoring)
    {           

        PropertyInfo fcmPi = typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        object o = fcmPi.GetValue(null, null);

        FieldInfo fi_dirMonSubdirs = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
        object monitor_dirMonSubdirs = fi_dirMonSubdirs.GetValue(o);

        MethodInfo m_dirMonSubdirs = monitor_dirMonSubdirs.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        m_dirMonSubdirs.Invoke(monitor_dirMonSubdirs, new object[] { });

        FieldInfo fi_dirMonAppPathInternal = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonAppPathInternal", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
        object monitor_dirMonAppPathInternal = fi_dirMonAppPathInternal.GetValue(o);

        if (monitor_dirMonAppPathInternal != null)
        {
            MethodInfo m_dirMonAppPathInternal = monitor_dirMonAppPathInternal.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            m_dirMonAppPathInternal.Invoke(monitor_dirMonAppPathInternal, new object[] { });
        }
        hasRemovedFoldersFromMonitoring = true;
    }
}
```

But, code does not fix the problem. I am still getting log out issue.

I also tried disabling FCNMode on registry editor like below:

```
 HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode
 Added the DWORD value of 1 to FCNMode
```

Still I am facing the problem.

Can someone please help me to resolve this IIS log out issue? I would like to fix the issue through coding.

I am okay with below:

By going in this way, if code changes will not be automatically identified after deployment by IIS. Then fine, I will manually restart IIS for this. But, I want application should not log out for the customers until session times out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "log out issue"? From context, it seems like you mean your customers are getting logged out when you do a deploy/update. If that is the case, you should be storing your user sessions in a cache / in-memory db like Redis, or even in your main database. When you restart an application, it will lose sessions. You should be storing them somewhere and reloading them. If I misunderstand the issue, describe a bit more about what the actual problem is.

Comment: Assuming the logout happens because the sessions are stored InProc, how about using a state server instead? Then the application restarting won’t affect sessions.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley, User getting logged out of the application every 2 or 5 minutes. When I have a look at event viewer I see `Event message: Application is shutting down. Reason: A subdirectory in the Bin application directory was changed or renamed`. This is because of anti-virus scan. To overcome this, code written in Global.asax. But not working. Even, FCNMode disable not working

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Thanks for the suggestion. I suggested that. But, client does not want to go for anything else. They strictly say Inproc. I do not know why they do not want to try State Server. Could you help me with InProc?

Comment: It seems strange that an anti-virus scan is altering any directories/files. It really shouldn't be. Which anti-virus is it? Can you give the anti-virus program/process read only rights to your site folder? Make sure it doesn't even have write access.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley, Anti-virus is McAfee. I will try giving read-only rights to bin folder. Will it be okay if I give read-only to Bin? What does it mean `subdirectory in the bin directory` in the error message? I do not have any subdirectory in the bin directory.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing that, It seems fairly vague. But on a side note, running anti-virus isn't necessarily bad, but you shouldn't need to in a properly locked down Windows Server. Why is it every 2 - 5 minutes also? Is anti-virus watching files for changes? With proper permissions and security on the server / site folders, that shouldn't be necessary. Another thing you can do is store uploads or transient changes to a different, external folder entirely so no files change in the site folder ever once deployed.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley, yes It's properly locked down. It's not necessary. But, security team will not agree with this. So, they are monitoring. I am not sure whether anti-virus watching files for changes. I am not making any change to the deployed folder. But getting the error like I mentioned above.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley, anti-virus scans .Net deployed folder. So, applicaton pool getting reset and customers facing log out issue. I do not have any control on monitoring part. Could you please help me to fix this through coding? Written code to stop monitoring. But, it seems still application getting monitored. Do now know how

Comment: Ok, application pool getting reset makes sense why you are losing sessions. Without knowing more about your authentication setup, look into storing your sessions outside your application, like in an in-memory key/value DB like Redis. Here is a quick link I found:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040453/ASP-NET-Session-State-Management-with-Redis-Local 
but just research storing Asp.Net (whatever version you're using) authentication sessions in persistent storage. This way, every time the app pool resets, the sessions will still be there.

Comment: But resetting the app pool every 2 - 5 minutes bc of anti-virus is just a really bad move in general. It takes time and resources to restart all the time. Running anti-virus on a deployed app is just really bad and unnecessary if the deployed files don't change.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley, Thanks for the Redis. I will try Redis. Yes running anti-virus on the deployed folder is really bad. I am against it. But, it's a part of the security standard for the client. Is there a way to stop monitoring using code? like tried above? stop monitoring for file changes? So, even anti-virus scans application will not log out

Comment: @AustinWinstanley, just now checked with team. Client already rejected Redis :(

Comment: That's rough. You don't have many options. Try taking away even read access from the anti-virus so it has no access whatsoever to the site files. But at some point, something has to give. The client can have unnecessary anti-virus with persistent session store (Redis), or they stop the anti-virus and don't use persistent session store. They'll have to make a choice.